# Is there any way to make notification listener for ios in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there any way to make notification listener for ios in the flutter

I need to get any notification that received on ios device in android there is some method to get the notification list not only that we will get a listener will trigger whenever a new notification is reived
So, similarly is there any other method available for ios

current flutter pub library only supported by android

Comment: Your question isn't clear; What notifications do you want to listen for?

Comment: Question updated with more details please check it

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible on iOS.

There is no way to get details of notifications for other apps, or even that a notification has been delivered for another app.